# Why hasn't this site already graduated?

Tags: discussion

As I'm sure most of us know, the beta period for Area 51 sites in theory is meant to last 90 days, after which this site should graduate from beta and become a fully-fledged beta site. 95 days gone already, and ['Excellent' ratings in all aspects of the site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics), and we've still heard nothing! What's up here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rumor has it that we're next; it seems that the process of actually designing the non-beta look of the sites is taking more work per site than was anticipated, slowing down the launches of the sites in the big bunch of sites that all started around the same time.

Comment: That's good news. Indeed, I think with only one web designer and a series of sites graduating one after the other, delays are becoming evident. Cheers for the info.

Comment: What changes when the site "graduates" from beta?

Comment: @Bill: We get a unique design (replacing the "sketch-y" beta look), the rep thresholds as listed in the FAQ are raised to the normal levels (see, e.g., the SO FAQ), we get removed from the list of in-progress sites on area51, and we get added to the footers of every launched site.  There may be other things, too, but those are the ones that I can think of offhand (and it's possible that I may not have something quite 100% correct).

Comment: @Isaac. Thanks. Is there a general place to look for answers to questions like that, i.e. meta^2 queries about the platform? E.g. another question I have is about the search language. I know one can do things like user:n, but what else? And how does one search comments?

Comment: @Bill: Generally, any questions and answers about the SE platform/area51 sites/anything that spans multiple SE sites (including S[OUF]/MSO) belong on [meta.SO, aka MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: The rumor is true. :) please stay tuned.

Comment: @Jin: How do you know?

Comment: @Charles: I believe Jin is the designer.

Comment: @Isaac, @Jin: Just seen the design - oh, nice!  Best looking SX site so far.